# give multiple href links for single image in magento

Tags: image, hyperlink, href

as we know ,there is an option to give multiple links in single image .

How to apply this for magento slideshow images.

ref : http://www.onextrapixel.com/2009/04/30/how-to-create-multiple-links-on-a-single-image-with-image-map/

please help me to find some solution.

thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

Select your image and look for properties ; in the corner there is an tool, see the polygon,rectangle and polygon tools:

[image]

After that draw which parts you want to get linked.